# Openpyxl: Identify same values in first column and merge other column(s)

Tags: python, merge, openpyxl

My excel sheet has ID-numbers in column A but at times, they are the same. In this case, I want the program to take the text in column I and concatenate it. Column I can have 1 to n rows with the same ID

Example:

From here

| Column A | Column I |
| --- | --- |
| 197 | this is example no 1 |
| 198 | this is |
| 198 | example no 2 |
| 199 | this is example no 3 |

to here

| Column A | Column I |
| --- | --- |
| 197 | this is example no 1 |
| 198 | this is example no 2 |
| 199 | this is example no 3 |

It's not important whether column A remains two rows or merges into one, what's central is that column I merges.

I have tried iterating over each row checking whether the row before and after are the same. But what I struggle with is to put the newly joined list in another column. Right now, the excel list I get doesn't look different to the source.

```
mylist = []
for cell in sheet['A']:
    mylist.append(cell.value)

textlist = []
for cell in sheet['I']:
    textlist.append(str(cell.value))

mergecount=0
startcell=1
sheet.insert_cols(10)


for row in range(1, len(mylist)):
    print(row, mylist[row-1], mylist[row])
    if mylist[row-1] == mylist[row]:
        mergecount += 1
    else:
        print(row, mylist[row-1], mylist[row], startcell, mergecount)
        if mergecount > 0:
            for text in textlist:
                newcells = ' '.join(text)
                cell.value = newcells
        mergecount = 0
        startcell = row+1
if mergecount > 0:
    for text in textlist:
        newcells = ' '.join(text)
        cell.value = newcells
workbook.save(file)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have rewritten a little bit the code trying to imitate your style and name of variables to make it easier to understand.

For the first part we can use the same capture of the data on lists that you have done:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook

file = "Book1.xlsx"
workbook = load_workbook(file)
sheet = workbook.active

mylist = []
for cell in sheet['A']:
    mylist.append(cell.value)

textlist = []
for cell in sheet['I']:
    textlist.append(str(cell.value))
```

After, we can create 2 new lists to save the new IDs and new text, I would iterate from 0 as a good practice instead of iterating from "1":

```
mylist_new = []
textlist_new = []
for row in range(0, len(mylist)):
    if row == 0:
        newtext = textlist[row]        
    else:
        if mylist[row-1] == mylist[row]:
            # The operator '+' is going to work to concatenate strings:
            newtext = newtext + ' ' + textlist[row]
        else:
            mylist_new.append(mylist[row-1])
            textlist_new.append(newtext)
            newtext = textlist[row]

# I need these last 2 lines to save the last values of both: IDs and text:
mylist_new.append(mylist[-1])
textlist_new.append(newtext)
```

Finally, you can save the data from the new lists on 2 different columns (in this example I will use the same worksheet on columns J (10th) and K (11th):

```
for row in range(0, len(mylist_new)):
    sheet.cell(row=row+1, column=10).value = mylist_new[row]

for row in range(0, len(textlist_new)):
    sheet.cell(row=row+1, column=11).value = textlist_new[row]

workbook.save(file)
```

I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just loop column A only and add the Column I text into a dictionary where the ID in Column A is the key.
Then clear and write the dictionary to same or to another Sheet.
In this example I have written to another Sheet called 'Combined'
This all assumes there is no data to be retained in Columns B - H.

```
import openpyxl


wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Book1.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

dict1 = {}
### loop Column A, set the ID in column A as the key and append all data with same ID to the same key in dict1
for cell in ws['A']:
    valA = cell.value                     # Column A value
    valB = cell.offset(column=8).value    # Column I value
    if valA in dict1:
        dict1[valA] += f" {valB}"
    else:
        dict1[valA] = valB

### Create new Sheet called Combined
ws_new = wb.create_sheet("Combined")

### Append data to the Sheet 'key' into Column A and 'val' into Column B 
for key, val in dict1.items():
    ws_new.append([f"{str(key)}", f"{val}"])

ws_new.insert_cols(2, 7)  # Insert columns so text is Column I

wb.save('Book1.xlsx')
```

Comment: Use a defaultdict ideally with a list and concatenate to strings at the end.

Answer (score 1):

This is an optimised version of @moken's version.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from openpyxl import load_workbook

values = defaultdict(list) # collect key, value pairs, extending as required

wb = load_workbook("Book1.xlsx")
ws1 = wb.active

for row in ws1.iter_rows(max_col=9, values_only=True):
    key = row[0]
    value = row[-1]
    if key and value: # skip rows with neither key nor value
        values[key].append(value)

ws2 = wb.create_sheet("consolidated")
for key, value in values.items():
   ws2.append([key, " ".join(value)])
```